# Is the theorem on self-duality of the Koszul complex from Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra incorrect?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and consider $R^3$ with basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$.

In Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra, it is described that there are isomorphisms $$\alpha: \wedge^1 R^3 \to (\wedge^2 R^3)^*$$ given by

$e_1 \mapsto (e_2 \wedge e_3)^*$,

$e_2 \mapsto -(e_1\wedge e_3)^*$,

$e_3 \mapsto (e_1 \wedge e_2)^*$,

and $$\beta: (\wedge^2 R^3)^* \to \wedge^2 (R^3)^*$$ given by

$(e_1\wedge e_2)^* \mapsto e_1^* \wedge e_2^*$,

$(e_1\wedge e_3)^* \mapsto e_1^* \wedge e_3^*$,

$(e_2\wedge e_3)^* \mapsto e_2^* \wedge e_3^*$.

---

In the Koszul complex of $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$, we have
$$d_x: \wedge^1 R^3 \to \wedge^2 R^3$$ given by

$e_1 \mapsto x\wedge e_1 = -x_2e_1 \wedge e_2 - x_3 e_1\wedge e_3$,

$e_2 \mapsto x\wedge e_2 = x_1e_1 \wedge e_2 -x_3e_2 \wedge e_3$,

$e_3 \mapsto  x \wedge e_3= x_1 e_1 \wedge e_3 + x_2 e_2 \wedge e_3$.

In the dual to the Koszul complex, we have $$\delta_x: \wedge^2 (R^3)^* \to \wedge^1 (R^3)^*$$ given by

$e_1^* \wedge e_2^* \mapsto x_1e_2^* - x_2e_1^*$,

$e_1^* \wedge e_3^* \mapsto x_1e_3^* - x_3e_1^*$,

$e_2^* \wedge e_3^* \mapsto x_2e_3^* - x_3e_2^*$.

---

Koszul duality says that $\beta\alpha d_x$ should equal $\delta_x\beta\alpha$, but this is not the case for the above maps.

For example, we have $\beta\alpha d_x: e_1 \mapsto -x_2e_3+x_3e_2$, but $\delta_x\beta\alpha: e_1 \mapsto x_2e_3-x_3e_2$.

All other squares commute.

I have also found the same problem when computing maps out of $\wedge^1 R^2$, $\wedge^1 R^4$, and $\wedge^3 R^4$; so I believe there is something wrong with maps out of odd wedge powers.

Comment: You can just let $\gamma_i={(-1)}^{i(i+1)/2}\beta_i$. As it is suggested in exercise 17.8 from the same book.

Comment: @user782932 What is $\gamma_i$? Exercise 17.8 says "Note that the identification of $\wedge^{n-k} (R^n)^*$ with $(\wedge^{n-k} R^n)^*$ requires some signs. "

Comment: I mean you just need to replace $\beta_i$ with $\gamma_i$ in the diagram to make it commute. This changes the signs.

Comment: @user782932 I just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, this does not work either. The signs in the isomorphism $(\wedge^{2} R^3)^* \to \wedge^{2} (R^3)^*$ switch, but the signs in the isomorphism $(\wedge^{1} R^3)^* \to \wedge^{1} (R^3)^*$ also switch. So, you get the same problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. You might be right. I couldn't remember it is $(-1)^{i(i+1)/2}$ or $(-1)^{i(i-1)/2}$, at least one should be true. It depends on the form of the signs when $\beta_i$   are unchanged, like $(-1)^i$ or $(-1)^{i-1}$ in terms of different indices.

Comment: Since in this case $\delta_x\beta_{i-1}\alpha_{i-1}=(-1)^{i-1}\beta_i\alpha_{i}d_x$. The change of sign should be $(-1)^{i(i-1)/2}$.

Comment: @user782932 I checked some examples and it seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: @user782932 May I ask, how did you figure that out?

Comment: If you can compute the general form $\delta_x\beta_{i-1}\alpha_{i-1}=(-1)^{i-1}\beta_i\alpha_idx$, and observe the identity $i(i-1)/2-(i-1)(i-2)/2=i-1$, then the result follows